# Adding Android library

Tags: android, addition

I've accidentally deleted the "Android 3.2" library (actually I wanted to replace it with "2.1"). Now I don't know how to add it back.

Here is before deleting:

[image]

And here I have android platforms:

[image]

I tried "Add external JARs", "Add Library" and others too but the end result is never the same as on the first screenshot and hence my app wont work).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, in Eclipse:
Window -> Android SDK Manager

Then install all the plattforms you want.

Then right click on project->properties->android and select the plattform you want ;)

Comment: Thanks, never had a "problem" like this before :)

Comment: But still, there is no change under Java Build Path. I think I should add it manually also?

Comment: "project->properties->android" selecting one of the android plattforms there should add it to your build path! if not, sorry but no idea...

Answer (score 0):

you need to change your manifest to `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />` (2.3.3) instead of using `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="12" />` (3.1).

for more information: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/api-levels.html